# How can I put an image in a QTextEdit outside of a regular text line?

Tags: c++, html, image, qt, css-position

I would like to be able to insert an image into a QTextEdit above any given letter in a line of text.

Initially, I thought I would be able to use the position:absolute attribute in an html object, but QTextDocument doesn't support that.  I've also tried inserting html images at the cursor, but the closest I can get with that approach is inserting an image in a text line which using html like this:

```
<img src="/smiley.png" style="position:absolute; left:200px; right:200px;" height="16" width="16"/>
```

results in something like this:

s:)miley

but I would want the smiley face to appear above the letter 'm' for example. (Sorry, can't post images)

This lead me to believe I would need to use the background-image attribute, but given that I am using a QTextEdit, I'm not sure what Qt object I would apply that to in order to get the image to appear only over the 'm'.

Does anyone have any tips for absolute positioning of images in QTextEdit?

*EDIT*

While that would put an image where the letter was, it would put the image in line with the text.  Whereas I want the image above the actual text. Like this:

:)
  smiley

Where the smile is above the text, but not on its own text line. Sort of in the space between lines.

Comment: you can do a search & replace right ? search for the letter you want to replace and replace it with <img>

Comment: how about using an overlay widget ?

Comment: @AmazingSixty that is a good option, but I also need to be able to save the HTML out to a file and the images wouldn't be represented in the HTML as an overlay widget.

Comment: So the best thing to do is to first figure out how to achieve your goal with HTML alone I guess